# How can I use split the string without changing previous string

Tags: java, android, regex, firebase

I am using the firebase to setup the email and default username, which is email address before"@"

This is the code below, and my email String also changing.

```
users
|- email: eric4619   // It should be eric4619@gmail.com
|- username: eric4619
```

I want to get a separated result such as email: eric4619@gmail and username: eric4619. not email: eric4619 and username: eric4619. Any help would appreciate

```
String email = et_email.getText().toString().trim();
String username = email.split("@")[0];    //keep changing my email string
String pwd = et_password.getText().toString().trim();
User usr = new User(email,username,pwd);
```

Comment: I guess there is issue in your User class. See the constructor where you are passing 3 parameters. They might not be properly mapped.

Comment: Hi, split is not changing Your email String. It is simply returning a new, splitted String. Debug the code if et_email really contains Your email, and as @SayantanMandal said, check the User class constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Using a split operation will never change the existing string. 
Can you print and ensure that ct_email.getText() returns eric4619@gmail.com and not just eric4619. If so the problem is there itself.

Comment: Yeah `String` is immutable, `split` will not _modify_ a `String`.  The problem is definitely not the `split`.